# Connect to the internet via routing through another PC?

Tags: windows, internet, ethernet, windows-server-2008-r2, internet-sharing

### Build

Windows 2008 R2 Server.
Two (2) Ethernet ports:

1. One Ethernet port, statically assigned to 192.168.2.4, is connected to an internal subnet (192.168.2.x), which I'm using for a local test Environnment.
2. The second Ethernet is connected to a larger network that is assigned by DHCP: address 192.168.15.61.

### Desired behavior

I want the computers on the .2.x subnet to use my server (.2.4) as a gateway to the internet. What do I need to do to get the routing to occur between the two Ethernet ports?

### What I've tried

- Tried to route add, but I think there's a detail I'm missing because I couldn't get that to work.
- I tried bridging the connections after some research, but that didn't give me the desired results. What else might I do?

Comment: First, do the machines on the .2.x subnet know to use that machine as their gateway to the Internet? Second, are you aware that this cannot be done with routing unless this machine's default gateway knows to send the reply packets to this machine.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on and configure the "Routing and Remote Access Services" (aka RRAS).  It's part of Windows Server, and it's for dealing with what it's named for - "Routing" and "Remote Access".

RRAS Overview:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469714.aspx
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_and_Remote_Access_Service

RRAS Configuration:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458979.aspx